# Observe layer frame size change in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

Is it possible to observe `self.layer.frame.size` change in `UICollectionViewCell`?

I tried to register observer do it like this:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.layer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(rawValue: 0), context: nil)
}
```

And then observe like this:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    print(keyPath ?? "NIL")
}
```

And it came out that `observeValue` method has been never called.

Comment: Why you just don't use layoutSubviews for this ?

Comment: My `UICollectionViewCell ` is changing size during the animation, but `layoutSubviews` gets called only when `frame.size` has been changed which means - before and after animation. I need to get sizes between those two states.

Comment: frame is not a property of layer use self.addObserver directly

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the var frame and add your function on `didSet`

```
override var frame: CGRect {
    didSet {
        //do something
    }
}
```